# How to add values to a mutable list to then add to an immutable one

Tags: list, kotlin, immutability, mutability

So I am using a custom SDK where I need to input a range of numbers, say from 1 to 100 as Strings into a listOf collection. Is there some efficient way this could be done with say a for loop? I barely have any experience with kotlin so all help is appreciated!

Comment: How can the framework impose a `listOf()` call? It probably simply expects the `List` type, but you should be free to build that list however you see fit. I don't quite understand your constraints here. I posted an answer with the way I would do it, but I'm not sure this matches your constraints.

Answer (score 2):

You can't really "add to an immutable [list]".

If you are already using a mutable list somewhere, then you can use `toList()` (like in @anber's answer) to get a read-only version or you could also directly pass it to a function expecting a `List` (if you don't change the list while the framework is using it).

If you simply want to build an immutable list of number strings from a range of numbers, this can be achieved using basic functional operations starting from the range object itself:

```
val list = (1..100).map { "$it" }
```

Note the Kotlin range syntax here. That way you don't really have to use a `for` loop, and you don't even have to use a temporary mutable list. Mutable stuff is not very idiomatic in Kotlin, unless it's part of the business.

You could also use `it.toString()` instead of the string template, but I find it more readable with the template.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly you can create mutable list, add items in loop, and then convert it to immutable list:

```
val mutableList = mutableListOf<String>()
for (i in 0..10) {
    mutableList.add(i.toString())
}
val immutableList = mutableList.toList()
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a function which looks like a constructor, but is actually top-level function. You can use it like this:

```
val l = List(99) { "${it + 1}" }
```

`l` will be of type `List<String>` (immutable).